# Do we want questions about "What are open source alternatives to X"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen the following question: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/219/40

And I wanted to have this particular policy discussed early.

Do we want question like: "What are open source software that do X?" or "What are open source alternatives to Y?"

Answer (score 23):

My stance is that no, we should not. We are a community of experts on the subject of open source projects, specifically, we know how to create, maintain, and use open source projects.

We do not have expertise in all the various open source projects out there, and there is a site specifically made for that over on **[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)**.

Comment: I agree with that. To be precise, I voted to close this particular question with the suggestion of it be more fitting for softwarerecs.se.

Comment: @Mnementh As did I. Stating you're only looking for OpenSource alternatives is completely acceptable at SR, there's no reason to handle it here.

Comment: I agree. It will just lower the tone of the site and the quality of stuff. And then we're just going to have close vote wars and stuff like that. Let's get it out. :)

Comment: This would be a nice one to add to the off-topic close reasons ;)